# Proving $\mathbb N$ isn't bounded

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbHP99sFX74&list=PLB-Mc4u93V4WwyRck9HACF2v_Q5V0bdNJ&index=5&t=2026s) video (@ ~33 mins) we're trying to prove a part of the [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property):

(i) For any $x \in \mathbb R$, there is an $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $ x < n$.

To do so the lecturer uses an "equivalent formulation of a supremum", video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRXbv-O9v0A&list=PLB-Mc4u93V4WwyRck9HACF2v_Q5V0bdNJ&index=6) (@ ~1:18:30):

**Proposition**: suppose $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ with upper bound $l$, denoted $A \leq l$. Then $l= \sup A$ if and only if for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $a \in A$ in the interval $(l-\epsilon, l]$.

Now, back in the proof of (i), the video proceeds as follows:

**Proof of (i)**

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\mathbb N \leq x$ for some $x \in \mathbb R$. Then, by the Axiom of Completeness, there is a least upper bound $l = \sup \mathbb N$. Then we know that there must be an $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $n \in (l-1, l]$. The proof then goes on but we now arrive at...

The confusing part/my question: in the above to get $n \in (l-1, l]$ we are taking $\epsilon = 1$ from the Proposition. However, the lecturer says in voice over that we could take $\epsilon$ to be any value, since the Proposition holds for any $\epsilon > 0$. But how can that be since we know that the elements of $\mathbb N$ are spaced out s.t. $|m-n|=1$ for any $m,n \in \mathbb N$ and $m \neq n$?

Phrased more loosely in words: I don't understand how we can take $\epsilon$ to be small and still expect to find a natural number in the interval $n \in (l-\epsilon, l]$.

Comment: Does this really need a proof ? If $x\le 0$ , then $n=1$ does the job. If $x>0$ , we can just take $n=\lceil x \rceil +1$ which is a natural number and surely greater than $x$. I just do not understand why videos are made about such trivial facts.

Comment: @Peter This is circular. The definition of $\lceil x \rceil$ relies on the Archimedean property.

Comment: Quote from the text (Understanding Analysis, page 21) justifying why we need to prove this: "In the absence of any other information about $\mathbb R$, we have to consider the possibility that in extending $\mathbb Q$ we unwittingly acquired some new numbers that are upper bounds for $\mathbb N$. In fact, as disorienting as it may sound, there *are* ordered field extensions of $\mathbb Q$ that include “numbers” bigger than every natural number."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might help to look at the case of a subset that *is* bounded, for instance $S=\{1,2,3\}$. The supremum of $S$ is $3$, and it is indeed true that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is an element of $S$ in $(3-\epsilon,3]$: namely, $3$ itself.

Now back to your proof: the argument is that *if* $\mathbb{N}$ were bounded with supremum $l$, then there would be a natural number in $(l-\epsilon, l]$ for any $\epsilon>0$. Note that this is *not* claiming that there is a natural number in $(x-\epsilon, x]$ for any arbitrary real number $x$: only when $x=l$, the hypothesized supremum of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Nice, thank you. So we have to have that $l \in \mathbb N$, I think that's where I got confused (and possibly still have a slight lingering discomfort here).

Answer (score 0):

Taking $\epsilon=1$ is convenient and just for the proof. With that he can do the trick to get the $l<n+1$. About finding a natural in $(l-\epsilon,l]$, since you are assuming that for every $\epsilon >0$ you can find a natural in that interval and, as you said naturals are spaced for at least one, if you take $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ you get that there is a natural in $(l-\frac{1}{2},l]$. If you take $\epsilon=\frac{1}{3}$ you get a natural in $(1-\frac{1}{3},l]$. As you take $\epsilon$ smaller you get a smaller interval near $l$, the coclussion is that the natural in $(l-\epsilon,l]$ is $l$ itself.